# How to pass array to sub or gsub in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have an array of characters I want to be removed from a string:

`stops = ["[", "]", "^", "(", ")", "#", "*", "?", "~"]`

I want to be able to pass the array and have all occurrences of those chars removed so that:

`"str [with] unwanted# char*acters"`

becomes

`"str with unwanted characters"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need to remove characters you can use `#delete`

```
str.delete "[]^()#*?~"
```

Comment: that was simple! haha :) better than using an array

Answer (score 10):

```
"str [with] unwanted# char*acters".gsub(Regexp.union(stops), '')
# => "str with unwanted characters"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str.tr('[]^()#*?~','')
str.tr('[]^()#*?~','abcdefghi')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.